# How to add 30 days to a XMLGregorianCalendar variable (Java & Authorize.net)

Tags: java

```
            GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
            gc.setTime(new Date());
            XMLGregorianCalendar startDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
            schedule.setStartDate(startDate); //2020-08-30
            
            XMLGregorianCalendar endDate = (XMLGregorianCalendar) startDate.clone();
            endDate.add(XMLGregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);
```

I'm getting `Cannot resolve symbol 'DAY_OF_MONTH'`.

Why am I using XMLGregorianCalendar? It's because I'm using Authorize.net as payment gateway and their official docs says it https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#recurring-billing-create-a-subscription

Tried `endDate.add(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED, 30);` too, but getting same error

Comment: I guess its just `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`

Comment: Tried it but got `Expected 1 arguments but found 2`

Comment: Do you want to add thirty calendar days? Or do you want to add thirty chunks of 24 hours? Not necessarily the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, the add method expects a Duration argument.
Try this:
`endDate.add(DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDurationDayTime(true, 30, 0, 0, 0));`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try:

```
endDate.add(DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newDuration("P30DT0H0M0S"));
```

Comment: Be aware that a `Duration` of 30 days is actually thirty chunks of 24-hours, *not* thirty calendar days. Calendar days can be other lengths, such as 23 hours, 25 hours, 23.5 hours and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the legacy date-time classes. Do your work using *java.time* classes. Then at the end convert to a legacy object as required by third-party library.

Capture the current moment as seen in the time zone of interest.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Add 30 days. These are thirty calendar days, not thirty chunks of 24 hours.

```
ZonedDateTime laterZdt = zdt.plusDays( 30 ) ;
```

Convert to legacy object. From the [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object, make a [`java.util.GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) object. From that make your [`javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) object.

```java
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = 
        DatatypeFactory
        .newInstance()
        .newXMLGregorianCalendar( 
            GregorianCalendar
            .from(
                laterZdt
            )
        ) 
;
```